# Consolidating Bugzilla instances

Tags: bugzilla, consolidation

Scenario:

- Two or more Bugzilla instances
- Want to migrate to one big central instance
- Bug numbers clash

What's the best practice for migrating all the bug records into the new instance? Is it a sufficiently common thing to want to do, that someone's made it easy?

Comment: Are you set on using Bugzilla?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/netscape.public.mozilla.webtools/browse_thread/thread/cacbf99f7d326c01/e1bd04cb84e61d59?lnk=gst&q=merge#e1bd04cb84e61d59), exporting the instances to XML was the way to go in 2004. I hope there is a better solution out there.